# Validation in express Rest Apis

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am saving signup value into database using expressjs in Rest api but how can i valuate my fields (name,email,password) so if i save without data then error message related to field should show
Here is my code

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
     host: "localhost",
      user: "root",
      password: "",
      database: "mydb"
    });

    var toTime = new Date();

      con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Connected!");
      var sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, email,password) VALUES ('"+req.body.name+"','"+req.body.email+"','"+req.body.password+"')";
      con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 record inserted");
         });
    });
```

Comment: As a side note: you're extremely open to SQL injection using non-parameterised queries like that.

Comment: @JayGould : not understand your point , please explain

Comment: `"+req.body.name+"` What if somebody input an SQL statement into `body.name` and escapes your current statement and injects their own SQL? Read more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: @JayGoulud : understand your point , i will change my code, but  what is solution for this ?

Comment: You should validate the parameters before sending them off to the SQL server. Also as suggested, this validation should check for injection attacks

Answer (score 0):

First note: you're code is susceptible to SQL injection. Refer: [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819826/how-to-pass-parameters-to-mysql-query-callback-in-nodejs)

Now, You can just make a validation function which returns `boolean`and use it before the query like

```
function validateFunc(...params){
    return params.reduce((p,c)=> p && (c !== null && c !== undefined), true);
}
```

And use it like,

```
if(!validateFunc(req.body.name, req.body.email, req.body.password)){
    // throw some error 
}
var sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, email,password) VALUES ('"+req.body.name+"','"+req.body.email+"','"+req.body.password+"')";
```