# Why isnt my data my being inseretd into my database

Tags: mysql, express, post, postman

Ok so I'm new very new to all this so I'm very sorry if don't spot the "obvious" problem. I'm trying to post data using POSTMAN but I keep getting this error. Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
{

    "error": {
        "code": "ER_PARSE_ERROR",
        "errno": 1064,
        "sqlMessage": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'itemData.GPU\", \"itemData.storage\", \"itemData.size\", \"itemData.price\")' at line 1",
        "sqlState": "42000",
        "index": 0,
        "sql": "INSERT INTO orderdetails (userID, title, device, type, CPU, RAM, GPU, storage, size, price) VALUES (\"itemdata.userID\", \"itemData.title\", \"itemData.device\", \"itemData.type\", \"itemData.CPU\", \"itemData.RAM, \"itemData.GPU\", \"itemData.storage\", \"itemData.size\", \"itemData.price\");"
    }
}
```

Data im trying to post:

```
{
    "userID":1,
    "title":"Nitro 5 Spin Laptop | NP515-51 | Black",
    "device":"laptop",
    "type":"Convertible",
    "CPU":"i5-8250U",
    "RAM":"8 GB",
    "GPU":"GTX 1050",
    "storage":"SSD",
    "size":"256 GB",
    "price":1099
}
```

.

```
 module.exports.add = function(conData, itemData, callback){
        db.connect(conData, function(err, conn){

            if (err) {
                callback(err);
                return;
            }

            conn.query("INSERT INTO orderdetails (userID, title, device, type, CPU, RAM, GPU, storage, size, price) VALUES (\"itemdata.userID\", \"itemData.title\", \"itemData.device\", \"itemData.type\", \"itemData.CPU\", \"itemData.RAM, \"itemData.GPU\", \"itemData.storage\", \"itemData.size\", \"itemData.price\");", itemData, function(err,result){

                callback(err, result);
            });
        });
```

Comment: What else are using using? Express or something else to POST the data to an endpoint? How are you get/setting the data from the request? Have you tried logging the Insert query to see what's actually coming through?

Comment: I just want to insert the data I currently have the POST data stored in itemData. How do i inset it into my mysql database

Comment: @salah You have a missing escaped double quote near the end of ‘itemData.RAM’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reference `itemData` as part of the string in the MySQL statement in `conn.query()`. You'll need to concatenate doing `VALUES (" + itemData.userID + ",` for all of the `itemData` values on that line. I also recommend looking into parameterization in order to protect your application from SQL injection. Here's a simple example: [How to pass parameters to mysql query callback in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819826/how-to-pass-parameters-to-mysql-query-callback-in-nodejs)

Comment: thank you that worked. Also, thank you for the example of sql injection