# Why won't Express.js variable route work?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

So I have the code, that calls to mySQL based on the route, however it does not work...

```
app.get("/attitude-chart/:att", function(req, res) {


    connection.query("SELECT * FROM actors ORDER BY id WHERE ?",{'attitude':`${req.params.att}`}, function(err, result) {

      var html = "<h1>Attitude-chart</h1>";

      html += "<ul>";

      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        html += "<li><p> ID: " + result[i].id + "</p>";
        html += "<p>Name: " + result[i].name + " </p></li>";
      }
      html += "</ul>";
      res.send(html);
    });

});
```

results are undefined....

Comment: Handle `err` in the callback first and then perform your processing (this is good practice), though not related to the question.

Comment: Will this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819826/how-to-pass-parameters-to-mysql-query-callback-in-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

You don't use a placeholder for the entire comparison expression. And the `ORDER BY` clause has to be after the `WHERE` clause.

You need to write:

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM actors WHERE attitude = :attitude ORDER BY id ",{'attitude': `${req.params.att}`}, function(err, result) {
```

The `:attitude` placeholder is replaced with the value of the `attitude` property of the object.

And if the column is numeric, you shouldn't put `req.params.att` in a template literal. You should pass the numeric value to the query.

Comment: Sql query is wrong `WHERE` cannot be preceded by `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what package you're using for MySQL, but it looks to me like your SQL is not well formed.

I would expect your query to look something like this:

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM actors WHERE attitude=?', req.params.att, ...)
```

This will result in an SQL query that looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM actores WHERE attitude='your value';
```

In your query, you have no `WHERE` expression, just a placeholder where an expression should be. I'm not familiar with *every* MySQL package out there, but every one I know of will require you to spell out what condition you're trying to match.

Comment: He might be used to ORM's like Laravel, where they take conditions this way.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Swapping WHERE and ORDER BY did the trick!

```
 connection.query("SELECT * FROM actors WHERE ? ORDER BY id",[{'attitude':`${x}`}], function(err, result) {
      console.log(result);
      var html = "<h1>Attitude-chart</h1>";

      html += "<ul>";

      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        html += "<li><p> ID: " + result[i].id + "</p>";
        html += "<p>Name: " + result[i].name + " </p></li>";
      }
      html += "</ul>";
      res.send(html);
    });
```