# Connection to SQL Server with Node.js doesn't work

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I have a big problem: I want to to connect to a MS SQL Server but whatever I am doing it doesn't work... I don't know where my mistake lies..

```
const parse = require("csv-parse/lib/sync");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
var mssql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');
var http = require('http');

// Connection to SSMS Database
var dbConfig = {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'user',
    server: 'server',
    database: 'database',
    options: {
        trustedConnection: true,
        useUTC: true
      }
};

var connection = new mssql.Connection(dbConfig, function(err) {
var request = new mssql.Request(connection);

...

 request.query(`INSERT INTO ${richtigername} (${namen}) VALUES (${values})`, function (err, recordset) {

                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err);

                                res.send(recordset)
                            } 

                            mssql.close();


                            });
```

Now there is the error message:

> TypeError: request is not a function

It is so difficult to get data into a SQL Server database.. the tool works fine with MySQL but SQL Server is horrible..

I have two more queries before this with also: `request.query(...)` and `if (err) { console.log(err); res.send(recordset)` ... MySQL is on the other hand so easy... only

`connection.query(...)` and before this

```
// Verbindung zur MySQL Datenbank
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'database'
});

and

 // Verbindung zur Datenbank starten
    connection.connect((error) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
        } else {

        }

    }) 
}
```

Comment: Firstly, SSMS isn't a database, it's a client tool. You're connecting to SQL Server. Secondly, please edit your question and add the info below. Do you actually have a SQL Server installed? Can you connect to it with a client tool (SSMS)

Comment: oh sry I know ;) yes I have sql server express and SSMS and also the database in SSMS ;)

Comment: but how i can test the connection?

Comment: i think you don't understand me .. First I have this tool for MySQL .. this works fine but now I have to rewrite this to SQL Server. I know that I must use the module mssql and also the style of the query's are a little bit different.

Comment: Assuming you want to connect to SQL Server from Node.js, [check the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/node-js/node-js-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). This doc section shows how to [install the correct driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/node-js/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-node-js-development?view=sql-server-ver15) (tedious), and [how to connect and execute queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/node-js/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-node-js?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: You'll see that the code required is *identical* to MySQL apart from the original connection. Only the dricres change

Comment: ok i will see ;) thanks :)

Comment: @Frederic what you wrote isn't a MySQL query either. You created a SQL string through string interpolation, exposing you to SQL injection attacks. You can use the same string in SQL Server but don't do that. The doc example for SQL Server shows how to use parameters. MySQL also supports parameters. Instead of passing them by name though, you have to [pass them by position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819826/how-to-pass-parameters-to-mysql-query-callback-in-nodejs)

Comment: Also we haven’t established whether you’ve installed SQL Server yet

Comment: I'm no node expert, but this sanple code https://www.npmjs.com/package/msnodesqlv8 looks nothing like yours. There's no `request` in this sample. Try using the sample code. And also confirm you actually have SQL Server installed

Answer (score 0):

First, assign a connection pool then use that to run your SQL.  This example uses a stored procedure, but it is easily modified to run a query.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    var sql = require("mssql");

    // config for your database
    var config = {
        user: 'user',
        password: 'yourpassword',
        server: 'yourserver', 
        database: 'yourdb' 
    };

  new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool => {
    return pool.request()
      // for select query, uncomment .query and comment .input and .execute
      //.query("select * from table1 where id = 2")
      // for stored proc, comment .query and uncomment .input and .execute
      // .input is only needed if proc has params
      .input('p_id', sql.Int, 5)
      .execute('getData')
    }).then(result => {
      let rows = result.recordset
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
      res.status(200).json(rows);
      sql.close();
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send({ message: "${err}"})
      sql.close();
    });

  });

var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```