# How set a value within connection.query function nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am trying to push rows in dataArray but it returns a blank array in the response.

```
 let dataArray = [];
            for (let id=1; id <= 5; id++) {
                dbConnection.query("SELECT firm_name, id FROM stockist WHERE id=?", id, function (error, rows) {
                    if (error) throw error;
                    else {
                        dataArray.push(rows);
                    }
                });
                // console.log("data "+id+" :", data);
            }
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass parameters to mysql query callback in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819826/how-to-pass-parameters-to-mysql-query-callback-in-nodejs)

Comment: Danizavtz thanks for your response. I am using mysql database.

Comment: thanks Nikhil Bhandari. this is not my problem, I want to push rows into global variable dataArray.

Answer (score 1):

You are using **Async / Await** which is an asynchronous operation hence it won't be possible for you to print the data outside of async. Hence you are going to have to store the async result in a variable and then simply check if data exist then print.

```
   let dataArray = [];

   for (let id=1; id <= 5; id++) {
        let result = null;
        result = await dbConnection.query("SELECT firm_name, id FROM stockist WHERE id=?", id);
        if (result) {
           console.log(result) //=====> it should contain all rows
           dataArray.push(result);
           // console.log("data "+id+" :", data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks Mr. Khan. But I want to push rows data into dataArray. is that possible?

Comment: Done. Check now. You don't need callback since you are using async/await just console.log it and you will find all rows in the result.

Comment: <ref *1> Query {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    error: [Function (anonymous)],
    packet: [Function (anonymous)],
    timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
    end: [Fun

Comment: result print this type of object. how I retrieve rows from that