# How can I make the code inside httpPost start working?

Tags: javascript, server

The objective of my code is to do register and login to the database and after the login it start the game, the register and log in are working fine, but for some reason when I click the confirm button in `confirmBtn.mousePressed(do_Login);` in the `function loginScreen()` this part of the code doesnt do anything, like it doesnt exist,

```
playerid=dataReceived[0].pl_id;
        
              remove_Login();
        
              mainSceneEnable=true;
              print(playerid)
```

inside the {} of the `httpPost('/login','json',player,(dataReceived)=>{` is not working, the objective of that code is to enter the function `remove_Login();` and enable the variable `mainSceneEnable`, with this the login screen should disapear and the game would start by activating the function `MenuHud()` in the `function draw()`

This code is very basic because I am new so dont expect much of it.

here is all the code.

sketch:

```
let playerid;

let booleanLog = true
let nameInput;
let passInput;
let confirmBtn;
let changeLoginRegisterBtn;

let goldBtn;

let mainSceneEnable=false;
let shopMenuBollean = true;

let shopMenu = ["Store", "Forge", "Workshop", "Enchanter", "Inventory", "Hero Management", "Upgrades"];

let villageMenu = ["Production", "Tavern", "Adventure Guild", "Upgrades"];

let drawSquare= 0

let shop = {
  text:"Shop",
  x:0,
  y:0,
  w:0,
  h:0
  }

let village = {
  text:"Village",
  x:0,
  y:0,
  w:0,
  h:0
  }

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);

  loginScreen()

}

function draw() {

  background(220);

  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER)
  textSize(20)

  //Change Between Login and Register text
  if(mainSceneEnable == false){
    if (booleanLog){
      text("LOGIN", windowWidth*0.52,windowHeight*0.25)
    }else{
      text("REGISTER", windowWidth*0.52,windowHeight*0.25)
    }
  }else{

    MenuHud()
  }
}

function mousePressed() {

  //Enables in game buttons
  if(mainSceneEnable){
    MenuButtons();
  }
}

function change_Login_Register() {

  if(booleanLog){
    booleanLog = false
  }else {
    booleanLog = true
  }
}

function loginScreen(){
  background(220);

  nameInput = createInput('');
  nameInput.position(windowWidth*0.45,windowHeight*0.3);
  passInput = createInput('');
  passInput.position(windowWidth*0.45,windowHeight*0.4);
  confirmBtn = createButton('Confirm');
  confirmBtn.position(windowWidth*0.45,windowHeight*0.45);
  confirmBtn.mousePressed(do_Login);

  changeLoginRegisterBtn = createButton('Change Between Login and Register');
  changeLoginRegisterBtn.position(windowWidth*0.38,windowHeight*0.17);
  changeLoginRegisterBtn.mousePressed(change_Login_Register);
}

function do_Login(){

  let username=nameInput.value();
  let password=passInput.value();


  let player = {
    username:username,
    password:password
  }

  //Do Login
  if (booleanLog){

    httpPost('/login','json',player,(dataReceived)=>{

      playerid=dataReceived[0].pl_id;

      remove_Login();

      mainSceneEnable=true;
      print(playerid)
    });

  //Do Register
  }else{
    httpPost('/register','json',player,(dataReceived)=>{

      playerid=dataReceived[0].pl_id;

    });
  }
}

function remove_Login(){

  nameInput.remove();
  passInput.remove();
  confirmBtn.remove();
  changeLoginRegisterBtn.remove();
}

function MenuHud(){
  
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER)
  textSize(20)
  fill(255)
  stroke("red")
  strokeWeight(2)
  
  shop.x = width/22;
  shop.y = height/6;
  shop.w = width/15;
  shop.h = height/12;
  
  village.x = width/9;
  village.y = height/6;
  village.w = width/15;
  village.h = height/12;
  
  //Shop or Village Menu options
  rect(shop.x, shop.y, shop.w, shop.h)
  text(shop.text, shop.x + shop.w/2, shop.y + shop.h/2)
  
  rect(village.x, village.y, village.w, village.h)
  text(village.text, village.x + village.w/2, village.y + village.h/2)
  
  //Mouse over to change bettween menus
  if(mouseX > shop.x && mouseX < shop.x+shop.w && mouseY > shop.y && mouseY < shop.y+shop.h){
    
    shopMenuBollean = true;
      
  }else if (mouseX > village.x && mouseX < village.x+village.w && mouseY > village.y && mouseY < village.y+village.h){
      
    shopMenuBollean = false;
  }

  //array for the menu options
  textSize(15)
  
  //Shop Menu
  if(shopMenuBollean == true) {
    
    for(let i=0; i<shopMenu.length; i++){
      rect(width/22, height/4+(i*height/12), width/7.55, height/12)
      text(shopMenu[i], width/9, height/3.5+(i*height/12));    
    }
  
  //Village Menu
  }else if(shopMenuBollean == false){
    
    for(let i=0; i<villageMenu.length; i++){
      rect(width/22, height/4+(i*height/12), width/7.55, height/12)
      text(villageMenu[i], width/9, height/3.5+(i*height/12));
    }
  }

  // Store
  if (drawSquare == 1){
    rect(width/5.54, height/1.72, width/1.4, height/3.99)
    rect(width/5.54, height/1.72, width/10, height/45) //Shop toggle
    rect(width/1.6, height/2, width/15, height/15) //NPCs in queue
    rect(width/1.4, height/6, width/3.55, height/1.501) //Inventory
    
  }
    
  //Forge
  else if (drawSquare == 2){
    rect(width/5.54, height/1.72, width/1.4, height/3.99)
    rect(width/5.54, height/6, width/1.8, height/2.43) //Forge Menu
    rect(width/4.2, height/5, width/9, height/7.5) //Material 1
    rect(width/2.6, height/5, width/9, height/7.5) //Material 2
    rect(width/1.89, height/5, width/9, height/7.5) //Material 3
    rect(width/2.55, height/2.72, width/10, height/45) //Craft Button
    rect(width/2.6, height/2.4, width/8, height/8) //Result
    rect(width/1.4, height/6, width/3.55, height/1.501) //Inventory
    
  }
  
  //Workshop
  else if (drawSquare == 3){
    rect(width/5.54, height/1.72, width/1.4, height/3.99) //Workshop Menu
    rect(width/4.9, height/1.6, width/11, height/8) //Item
    rect(width/3.2, height/1.6, width/11, height/8) //Gold
    rect(width/2.38, height/1.6, width/11, height/8) //Material
    rect(width/2.55, height/1.3, width/10, height/45) //Upgrade Button
    rect(width/1.65, height/1.6, width/11, height/8) //Result
    rect(width/1.4, height/6, width/3.55, height/1.501) //Inventory
  }
  
  //Enchanter
  else if (drawSquare == 4){
    rect(width/5.54, height/1.72, width/1.4, height/3.99) //Enchant Menu
    rect(width/4.9, height/1.6, width/11, height/8) //Item
    rect(width/3.2, height/1.6, width/11, height/8) //Gold
    rect(width/2.38, height/1.6, width/11, height/8) //Enchantment
    rect(width/2.55, height/1.3, width/10, height/45) //Enchant Button
    rect(width/1.65, height/1.6, width/11, height/8) //Result
    rect(width/1.4, height/6, width/3.55, height/1.501) //Inventory
    //rect(width/2.6, height/2.4, width/8, height/8) //Enchant Preview When Mouse Hover
    
  }

  //Inventory
  else if (drawSquare == 5){
    rect(width/5.54, height/6, width/1.25, height/1.501) //Inventory
   
  }

  //Heroes Management
  else if (drawSquare == 6){
    rect(width/5.54, height/6, width/1.25, height/1.501) //Hero Menu
    rect(width/2.8, height/2, width/1.6, height/3.01) //Inventory
    rect(width/3.6, height/1.8, width/15, height/45) //Clock 
    rect(width/2.8, height/5, width/9, height/7.5) //Slot 1
    rect(width/2.1, height/5, width/9, height/7.5) //Slot 2
    rect(width/1.68, height/5, width/9, height/7.5) //Slot 3
    rect(width/1.4, height/5, width/9, height/7.5) //Slot 4
    rect(width/1.2, height/5, width/9, height/7.5) //Slot 5
    rect(width/2.8, height/2.5, width/4, height/15) //Time
    
  }

  //Upgrades
  else if (drawSquare == 7){
    rect(width/5.54, height/1.72, width/1.4, height/3.99)
    
  }

  //Tavern
  else if (drawSquare == 8){
    rect(width/5.54, height/1.72, width/1.4, height/3.99)
    
  }
}

function MenuButtons(){
  
  //Shop Menu
  if(shopMenuBollean == true) {
    
  //Store
  if(mouseX > width/22 && mouseX < width/22+width/7.55 && mouseY > height/4+(0*height/12) && mouseY < height/4+(0*height/12)+height/12){
    drawSquare= 1
    
  }
    
  //Forge
  else if(mouseX > width/22 && mouseX < width/22+width/7.55 && mouseY > height/4+(1*height/12) && mouseY < height/4+(1*height/12)+height/12){
    drawSquare= 2
    
  }
    
  //Workshop
  else if(mouseX > width/22 && mouseX < width/22+width/7.55 && mouseY > height/4+(2*height/12) && mouseY < height/4+(2*height/12)+height/12){
    drawSquare= 3
    
  }
    
  //Enchanter
  else if(mouseX > width/22 && mouseX < width/22+width/7.55 && mouseY > height/4+(3*height/12) && mouseY < height/4+(3*height/12)+height/12){
    
   drawSquare= 4
    
  }
    
  //Inventory
  else if(mouseX > width/22 && mouseX < width/22+width/7.55 && mouseY > height/4+(4*height/12) && mouseY < height/4+(4*height/12)+height/12){
    
    drawSquare= 5
    
  }
    
  //Heroes Management
  else if(mouseX > width/22 && mouseX < width/22+width/7.55 && mouseY > height/4+(5*height/12) && mouseY < height/4+(5*height/12)+height/12){
    
    drawSquare= 6
    
  }
    
  //Upgrades
  if(mouseX > width/22 && mouseX < width/22+width/7.55 && mouseY > height/4+(6*height/12) && mouseY < height/4+(6*height/12)+height/12){
    drawSquare= 7
    
  }
    
  // Village Menu
  }else if(shopMenuBollean == false) {
    
  //Tavern
  if(mouseX > width/22 && mouseX < width/22+width/7.55 && mouseY > height/4+(0*height/12) && mouseY < height/4+(0*height/12)+height/12){
    drawSquare= 8
    
  }

  //Wood
  else if(mouseX > width/22 && mouseX < width/22+width/7.55 && mouseY > height/4+(1*height/12) && mouseY < height/4+(1*height/12)+height/12){
    drawSquare= 9
    
  }
    
  //Mine
  else if(mouseX > width/22 && mouseX < width/22+width/7.55 && mouseY > height/4+(2*height/12) && mouseY < height/4+(2*height/12)+height/12){
    drawSquare= 10
    
    }
  }
}
```

Server:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mysql = require('mysql');
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(express.static('public'));

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
 
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

//creates instance to make connection to the sql database
const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  port: 3306,
  user: "root",
  password: "root",
  database: "heroshoppe",
  //WORKING WITH MAMP ON MAC!!!

});

db.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected to DB!");
});

app.post('/register',(req,res)=>{

let username = req.body.username;
let password = req.body.password;
let gold = 1000;

let sql = "SELECT * FROM Player WHERE pl_name='"+username+"'";

        db.query(sql,(err,result)=>{
        if(err) throw err;

        //no player with that name
        if(result.length<1){

            let sql = "INSERT INTO Player (`pl_name`,`pl_pass`,`pl_gold`) VALUES ('"+username+"','"+password+"','"+gold+"')";

            db.query(sql,(err,result)=>{
            if(err) throw err;

            //if affected rows
                let sql = "SELECT pl_id FROM Player WHERE pl_name='"+username+"' AND pl_pass='"+password+"'";

                db.query(sql,(err,result)=>{
                    if(err) throw err;

                    console.log(result);

                    res.send(result);
                });
            });
        }
    });
});

app.post('/login',(req,res)=>{

let username = req.body.username;
let password = req.body.password;

let sql = "SELECT * FROM Player WHERE pl_name='"+username+"'";

        db.query(sql,(err,result)=>{
        if(err) throw err;

        console.log(result);
        if(result.length>1){

            let sql = "SELECT pl_id FROM Player WHERE pl_name='"+username+"' AND pl_pass='"+password+"'";

                db.query(sql,(err,result)=>{
                if(err) throw err;

                console.log(result);

                res.send(result);
            });
        }
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Comment: Your code is likely wide open to a critical SQL injection vulnerability. You should be using [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819826/how-to-pass-parameters-to-mysql-query-callback-in-nodejs) to mitigate this.

Comment: Additionally, "*it's not working*" isn't a particularly helpful problem statement. Please edit your question to include a succinct explanation of why your attempt isn't meeting your requirements, being sure to include the full text of any and all pertinent error messages you're seeing. See also: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)